# Delete hidden grouped rows below selected summary row

Tags: excel, vba

I use the below code in a macro to copy all rows from a "Template" sheet and paste them to the active sheet. Then all except the first of the pasted rows are grouped and "collapsed" i.e RowLevels:=1.

```
If .Outline.SummaryRow <> xlSummaryAbove Then .Outline.SummaryRow = xlSummaryAbove
            csLastRow = copySheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            copySheet.Range("2:" & csLastRow).Copy
            .Rows(LRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
            .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End _
                                           (xlUp).Offset(-(csLastRow - 3), 1)).EntireRow.Group
             ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1, ColumnLevels:=0
```

This macro is run over and over to create a long list of summary rows with collapsed grouped rows below each as shown in the image.

[image]

The intention is to be able to delete a summary row and the collapsed group below it, if no longer needed on the sheet. As expected, when done manually, clicking on the summary row and deleting it, only deletes the summary row and appends the hidden rows below it to an adjacent group.

Is there a way to select the summary row and delete it along with the hidden grouped rows below it? How could I reference the first and last rows of a group in relation to the selected summary row above it in order to delete with vba?

Comment: Your question is not clear and sounds strange... 1. What does "any of the groups including its summary" means? **Based on what** to find that specific group? 2.  Why this, at least, strange request: **"without having to expand it"**? Like you could see, trying to delete it manually, **it is not possible**. But, just from curiosity, **why do you want deleted it in that impossible way**?

Comment: I could see deleting it manually was not possible, which is why I ask the question to see if there is another way. The reason I want to do it this way is to eliminate extra steps i.e expanding the group and then selecting 82 rows.

Comment: What you did is not so elegant, on my taste. You edited the question, deleted the strange words I mentioned above (showing them between double quotes), not mentioning anything about that and comes with a different approach. In such terms, the answer is, yes, it is possible to delete a whole group (not without having to expand **it**), without expanding all groups on the sheet. But, in order to be helped, **you should answer my first question**. Do you expect an explanation or a piece of code doing what you require? For the last option, defining the way of nominating the group it is mandatory.

Comment: Please, test the answer code and send some feedback.

Comment: I was referring to "The intention is to be able to delete any of the groups including its summary row when required, without having to expand it", from where I copied "**without having to expand it**".

Comment: The way to clarify the question was too remove some words, and add some words, I dont think this needs to be discussed further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test the next code. Since your picture does not show the columns headers (if any of them is hidden), the code assumes that you want to qualify the group to be deleted according to its cell value in column "B:B" (see `strCat` value):

```
Sub DeleteSpecificGroup() 
   Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, firstR As Long, cellC As Range
   Dim strCat As String, i As Long, firsGRow As Long, lastGRow As Long

    strCat = "Category 3"      'use there the category you need
       Set ws = ActiveSheet   'use here the sheet you need
       lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
       Set cellC = ws.Range("B2:B" & lastRow).Find(What:=strCat, After:=ws.Range("B2"), _
                                                                        LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
       If Not cellC Is Nothing Then
           firsGRow = cellC.row                      'first row of the group to be deleted
            If ws.rows(cellC.row + 1).OutlineLevel > 1 Then
                 For i = cellC.row + 1 To lastRow
                     If ws.rows(i).EntireRow.ShowDetail Then
                        ws.rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False
                     Else
                         lastGRow = i - 1: Exit For  'last row of the group to be deleted
                     End If
                 Next i
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox strCat & " could not be found in column ""B:B""...": Exit Sub
        End If
         ws.rows(firsGRow & ":" & lastGRow).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

To delete the group based on the group summary row selection, plese use the next code:

```
Sub DeleteSpecificSelectedGroup()
   Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, firstR As Long
   Dim i As Long, firsGRow As Long, lastGRow As Long
      
       Set ws = ActiveSheet   'use here the sheet you need
       lastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
           If ws.Outline.SummaryRow <> xlSummaryAbove Then ws.Outline.SummaryRow = xlSummaryAbove
           firsGRow = Selection.Row
           Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            If ws.Rows(firsGRow + 1).OutlineLevel > 1 Then
                 For i = firsGRow + 1 To lastRow + 500
                     If ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.ShowDetail And ws.Rows(i).OutlineLevel > 1 Then
                        ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False
                     Else
                         lastGRow = i - 1: Exit For  'last row of the group to be deleted
                     End If
                 Next i
            End If
         ws.Rows(firsGRow & ":" & lastGRow).EntireRow.Delete
         Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```